# Change the reference point for CSS position

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to lay out a page using divs.  I'm struggling because the reference point to a `<div>` seems to be the top left.  This is okay, until the div changes shape.  Then, the position via the top left isn't suitable.

If you see http://jsfiddle.net/jdb1991/8Xb7L/, you will get a live example of

```
#point { position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; }
#square { border: solid black 1px; height: 100px; width: 100px; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; }

<div id="point">+</div>
<div id="square"></div>
```

Is there a way, using CSS, to change the "reference point" of the square to be either the centre, or a different corner?

Comment: What do you mean by 'reference point'?

Comment: If you want the plus to be inside the box, then make that div a child of the other.

Comment: I'm not trying to put the point in the box, sorry for the confusion.  That's just here to show the centre of the screen and the fact that that's were the top left of the square is aligning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to put the `point` inside the `square`, then give the `square` `position: relative`. The position of the point will then be relative to the square (i.e. `left` will be the distance from the left edge of the square.)

```
#point { position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; }
#square { position: relative; border: solid black 1px; height: 100px; width: 100px; position: absolute; top: 50%; left: 50%; }
```

---

```
<div id="square">
  <div id="point">+</div>
</div>
```

---

If you want to use a different corner for positioning, use the `right` or `bottom` properties instead of `left` or `top`.

If you wish to position from the center, do what I suggested with the square, but give it a `0` width and height. The square will now be at the center and the point is positioned relative to it. Obviously you lose the width and height, so using percents for `left` and `top` won't work any longer.

Comment: I'm not trying to put the point in the box, sorry for the confusion.  That's just here to show the centre of the screen and the fact that that's were the top left of the square is aligning.

Comment: Please see the additional comment.

Comment: +1 Thanks for the update, that's given me something to work with.  Apologies for the poor wording to begin with.

Answer (score 0):

Besides setting width and height to `0`, which might have some undesirable consequences, another possible solution would be to give a negative left margin equal to exactly half the full box width, and a negative top margin equal to exactly half the full box height, where full width/height = width/height + border + padding.

For the box in your fiddle, which has width/height of 100 pixels and a 1 pixel border, this would mean adding

```
margin-left: -51px;
margin-top: -51px;
```